# Как проверить наличие файла в автозагрузке (реестр)?

Tags: c#

Как организовать добавление программы в автозагрузку через запись в реестре, перед этим проверив, есть ли данная программа уже в автозагрузке (чтобы защититься от повторного добавления записи в реестр)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для добавления записи о программе в автозагрузку нет необходимости проверять наличие записи. Запись производится по паре (ключ, значение) и при её наличии произойдёт перезапись значения.

```
RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");
registry.SetValue("My Application Name", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
registry.Close();
```

где, `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` - путь к файлу приложения (в моём случае приложение само себя добавляет в автозагрузку).

Пример записи с аргументами запуска:

```
registry.SetValue("My Application Name", '"' + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + '"' + " /taskbar");
```

Пример для произвольно пути:

```
registry.SetValue("My Application Name", "D:/MyAppFolder/MyApplication.exe");
```

А вот для удаления записи придётся проверять наличие ключа. В противном случае можно поймать исключение.

```
RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");

if (registry.GetValue("My Application Name") != null)
    registry.DeleteValue("My Application Name");

registry.Close();
```

Желательно такие конструкции оборачивать в `try/catch`.

Comment: А если файле, который нужно добавить в автозагрузку, например, test.exe
Уже есть в Ресурсах программы

Comment: @АндрейЛёвушкин Не понял вас.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lun23f

Comment: @АндрейЛёвушкин все ресурсы программы подгружаются автоматически с её запуском. Ничего и никуда добавлять не нужно. Если ваша программа имеет несколько исполняемых файлов, то указывайте путь к нужному EXE файлу.

Comment: Можно пример записи для файла, который находится по пути /xxx/yyy
Немного не понятно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @АндрейЛёвушкин добавил вариант с произвольным значением.

Comment: Пробую запустить подобное, для теста вывожу сообщение (проверить при перезагрузке устройства наличие в автозагрузке). Но в реестре смотрю - запись не добавляется после запуска и отработки приложения:
http://prntscr.com/luojbv

Comment: @АндрейЛёвушкин всё [добавляется](http://joxi.ru/xAeJRM4uRgkYEr). Возможно вы смотрите не там где нужно. Автозапуск находится в ветке реестра текущего пользователя HKEY_CURRENT_USER.